# Как вывести react компоненты в цикле по названию

Tags: reactjs

//импорт компонентов

```
import Accessible           from ''
import Ambulance            from ''
import Heartbeat            from ''
import Hospital             from ''
import HSquare              from ''
import Medkit               from ''
import Stethoscope          from ''
import UserMd               from ''
```

//массив названий

```
const serviceIcons = ['Accessible', 'Ambulance', 'Heartbeat', 'Hospital', 'HSquare', 'Medkit', 'Stethoscope', 'UserMd']
```

//вызов ф-и showIconsSpeciality, которая должна вывести все иконки

```
<div>
  {
    serviceIcons.map(this.showIconsSpeciality)
  }
</div>
```

//сама ф-я showIconsSpeciality

```
showIconsSpeciality = (nameIcon, i) => { 
    return React.createElement(
    'div',
    { key: i },
    React.createElement(nameIcon , {
      name: nameIcon,
      color: '#a5a5a5',
      style: {
        transition: 'all .5s 0',
        width: '40px'
      }
    })
  );           
  }
```

ПРОБЛЕМА заключается в том что создается просто ЭЛЕМЕНТ в цикле , а мне нужно что б вызывался КОМПОНЕНТ в цикле. Например `<Accessible .../>`

На данный момент получается `<accessible ...></accessible>`

Помогите вывести компоненты.

Answer (score 0):

Массив должен быть не с названиями элементов, а с самими элементами из импортов:

```
const serviceIcons = [Accessible, Ambulance, Heartbeat, Hospital, HSquare, Medkit, Stethoscope, UserMd]
```

т.к. первый параметр createElement должен быть либо строкой имени тега (например, 'div' или 'span'), либо типом компонента React (класс или функция).